# What is an easy way to build CGAL mesh out of DICOM sequence?

Tags: image-processing, mesh, image-segmentation, cgal, medical-imaging

I have a sequence of DICOM images constituting a single scan. I would like to build a CGAL mesh representing 3D volume segmented out of that scan by thresholding. I prefer Windows and few, easy to build dependencies, if any.

I've heard that ITK can be used for this purpose, but it is a large library with a lot of overlap with CGAL. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example CGAL-4.9/examples/Mesh_3/mesh_3D_gray_vtk_image.cpp  should be a good starting point.    As this is not easy to find we will add a link to it in the CGAL User manual, see the [pull request on github](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/1936)

Comment: Thank you for updating the documentation.